# Argument 'expression' cannot be converted to type 'DBNull'

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an app by vb for taking a list of doneators in Dvg and have about 17 forum and local mssql db and using if not is dbnull expression and by pressing the button some calculation happened and the answer appears in labels on the fourm..  But A strange problem happened when I run this app by the visual studio 2017 it run perfectly  and there is no error..  But when converting it to exe file and setup it the following error appear when pressing this button " Argument 'expression' cannot be converted to type 'DBNull'
" although it's not appear when run it with visual studio..  What could the problem be..?

here is the code but i don't think the problem in it because it works fine in visual studio 
its long code so i will put a part of it and the rest is repeated for 12 months and 10 years[this is pic of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnVu0.jpg)

```
 If Form1.ComboBox1.Text = "2018" Then

            ' total kfalat
            If TextBox1.Text = "1" Then

                Form5.total.Text = Form1.Table1DataGridView.Rows.Count - 1

                Dim HoN As Integer = 0
                ' total done
                For Each gvRow As DataGridViewRow In Form2.TableDataGridView.Rows
                    If Not IsDBNull(gvRow.Cells(13).Value) Then

                        If Val(Me.TextBox2.Text) <= Val(gvRow.Cells(13).Value) AndAlso Val(gvRow.Cells(13).Value) <= Val(Me.TextBox3.Text) Then

                            If Not IsDBNull(gvRow.Cells(1).Value) Then
                                Dim strNgheo As String = gvRow.Cells(1).Value
                                If strNgheo = "1" Then
                                    HoN = HoN + 1
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
                Form5.done.Text = HoN.ToString
                'undone
                Form5.notdone.Text = Val(Form5.total.Text) - Val(Form5.done.Text)

                'asbab 3adam alta7seel

                'lm yarod

                Dim HoN11 As Integer = 0

                For Each gvRow As DataGridViewRow In Form2.TableDataGridView.Rows
                    If Not IsDBNull(gvRow.Cells(13).Value) Then

                        If Val(Me.TextBox2.Text) <= Val(gvRow.Cells(13).Value) AndAlso Val(gvRow.Cells(13).Value) <= Val(Me.TextBox3.Text) Then

                            If Not IsDBNull(gvRow.Cells(1).Value) Then
                                Dim strNgheo As String = gvRow.Cells(1).Value
                                If strNgheo = "لم يرد" Then
                                    HoN11 = HoN11 + 1
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
                Form5.Label69.Text = HoN11.ToString

                'lmo2agal

                Dim HoN12 As Integer = 0

                For Each gvRow As DataGridViewRow In Form2.TableDataGridView.Rows
                    If Not IsDBNull(gvRow.Cells(13).Value) Then

                        If Val(Me.TextBox2.Text) <= Val(gvRow.Cells(13).Value) AndAlso Val(gvRow.Cells(13).Value) <= Val(Me.TextBox3.Text) Then

                            If Not IsDBNull(gvRow.Cells(1).Value) Then
                                Dim strNgheo As String = gvRow.Cells(1).Value
                                If strNgheo = "مؤجل" Then
                                    HoN12 = HoN12 + 1
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
                Form5.Label67.Text = HoN12.ToString

                'سيحضر

                Dim HoN13 As Integer = 0

                For Each gvRow As DataGridViewRow In Form2.TableDataGridView.Rows
                    If Not IsDBNull(gvRow.Cells(13).Value) Then

                        If Val(Me.TextBox2.Text) <= Val(gvRow.Cells(13).Value) AndAlso Val(gvRow.Cells(13).Value) <= Val(Me.TextBox3.Text) Then

                            If Not IsDBNull(gvRow.Cells(1).Value) Then
                                Dim strNgheo As String = gvRow.Cells(1).Value
                                If strNgheo = "سيحضر " Then
                                    HoN13 = HoN13 + 1
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
                Form5.Label65.Text = HoN13.ToString


                Dim HoN10 As Integer = 0
                Dim money As Integer = 0
                ' astmarat gdeda
                For Each gvRow As DataGridViewRow In Form1.Table1DataGridView.Rows
                    If Not IsDBNull(gvRow.Cells(8).Value) Then

                        If Val(Me.TextBox2.Text) <= Val(gvRow.Cells(8).Value) AndAlso Val(gvRow.Cells(8).Value) <= Val(Me.TextBox3.Text) Then

                            If Not IsDBNull(gvRow.Cells(15).Value) Then
                                'Dim strNgheo As Integer = gvRow.Cells(19).Value
                                ' If strNgheo = (gvRow.Cells(19).Value = True) Then
                                If gvRow.Cells(15).Value > 0 Then

                                    HoN10 = HoN10 + 1
                                    ' ElseIf gvRow.Cells(19).Value = False Then
                                    '    End
                                    money = money + Val(gvRow.Cells(15).Value)

                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
                Form5.Label59.Text = HoN10.ToString

                Form5.Label58.Text = money.ToString


                Dim orphensmoney1 As Integer = 0
                Dim HoN1 As Integer = 0

                Dim familiesmoney1 As Integer = 0
                Dim HoN2 As Integer = 0

                Dim sicksmoney1 As Integer = 0
                Dim HoN3 As Integer = 0

                Dim studentsmoney1 As Integer = 0
                Dim HoN4 As Integer = 0
                ' alkafalat almotwagda belf3l
                For Each gvRow As DataGridViewRow In Form1.Table1DataGridView.Rows

                    If Not IsDBNull(gvRow.Cells(19).Value) Then
                        'Dim strNgheo As Integer = gvRow.Cells(19).Value
                        ' If strNgheo = (gvRow.Cells(19).Value = True) Then
                        If gvRow.Cells(19).Value = True Then

                            HoN1 = HoN1 + 1
                            ' ElseIf gvRow.Cells(19).Value = False Then
                            '    End
                            orphensmoney1 = orphensmoney1 + Val(gvRow.Cells(23).Value)

                        End If
                    End If
                    If Not IsDBNull(gvRow.Cells(20).Value) Then
                        'Dim strNgheo As Integer = gvRow.Cells(19).Value
                        ' If strNgheo = (gvRow.Cells(19).Value = True) Then
                        If gvRow.Cells(20).Value = True Then

                            HoN2 = HoN2 + 1
                            ' ElseIf gvRow.Cells(19).Value = False Then
                            '    End
                            familiesmoney1 = familiesmoney1 + Val(gvRow.Cells(24).Value)

                        End If
                    End If

                    If Not IsDBNull(gvRow.Cells(21).Value) Then
                        'Dim strNgheo As Integer = gvRow.Cells(19).Value
                        ' If strNgheo = (gvRow.Cells(19).Value = True) Then
                        If gvRow.Cells(21).Value = True Then

                            HoN3 = HoN3 + 1
                            ' ElseIf gvRow.Cells(19).Value = False Then
                            '    End
                            sicksmoney1 = sicksmoney1 + Val(gvRow.Cells(25).Value)

                        End If
                    End If

                    If Not IsDBNull(gvRow.Cells(22).Value) Then
                        'Dim strNgheo As Integer = gvRow.Cells(19).Value
                        ' If strNgheo = (gvRow.Cells(19).Value = True) Then
                        If gvRow.Cells(22).Value = True Then

                            HoN4 = HoN4 + 1
                            ' ElseIf gvRow.Cells(19).Value = False Then
                            '    End
                            studentsmoney1 = studentsmoney1 + Val(gvRow.Cells(26).Value)

                        End If
                    End If



                Next
                Form5.Label11.Text = HoN1.ToString
                Form5.Label10.Text = orphensmoney1.ToString
                Form5.Label14.Text = HoN2.ToString
                Form5.Label13.Text = familiesmoney1.ToString
                Form5.Label17.Text = HoN3.ToString
                Form5.Label16.Text = sicksmoney1.ToString
                Form5.Label20.Text = HoN4.ToString
                Form5.Label19.Text = studentsmoney1.ToString

                Form5.Label8.Text = (Val(HoN1) + Val(HoN2) + Val(HoN3) + Val(HoN4)).ToString
                Form5.Label9.Text = (Val(orphensmoney1) + Val(familiesmoney1) + Val(sicksmoney1) + Val(studentsmoney1)).ToString



                Dim HoN5 As Integer = 0
                Dim ORPHENS As Integer = 0
                Dim HoN6 As Integer = 0
                Dim families As Integer = 0
                Dim HoN7 As Integer = 0
                Dim sicks As Integer = 0
                Dim HoN8 As Integer = 0
                Dim students As Integer = 0

                ' almo7asal fe kol band

                For Each gvRow As DataGridViewRow In Form2.TableDataGridView.Rows

                    If Not IsDBNull(gvRow.Cells(13).Value) Then
                        If Val(Me.TextBox2.Text) <= Val(gvRow.Cells(13).Value) AndAlso Val(gvRow.Cells(13).Value) <= Val(Me.TextBox3.Text) Then

                            If Not IsDBNull(gvRow.Cells(14).Value) Then
                                'Dim strNgheo As Integer = gvRow.Cells(19).Value
                                ' If strNgheo = (gvRow.Cells(19).Value = True) Then
                                If gvRow.Cells(14).Value > 0 Then

                                    HoN5 = HoN5 + 1
                                    ' ElseIf gvRow.Cells(19).Value = False Then
                                    '    End
                                    ORPHENS = ORPHENS + Val(gvRow.Cells(14).Value)

                                End If
                            End If

                            If Not IsDBNull(gvRow.Cells(16).Value) Then
                                'Dim strNgheo As Integer = gvRow.Cells(19).Value
                                ' If strNgheo = (gvRow.Cells(19).Value = True) Then
                                If gvRow.Cells(16).Value > 0 Then

                                    HoN6 = HoN6 + 1
                                    ' ElseIf gvRow.Cells(19).Value = False Then
                                    '    End
                                    families = families + Val(gvRow.Cells(16).Value)

                                End If
                            End If

                            If Not IsDBNull(gvRow.Cells(18).Value) Then
                                'Dim strNgheo As Integer = gvRow.Cells(19).Value
                                ' If strNgheo = (gvRow.Cells(19).Value = True) Then
                                If gvRow.Cells(18).Value > 0 Then

                                    HoN7 = HoN7 + 1
                                    ' ElseIf gvRow.Cells(19).Value = False Then
                                    '    End
                                    sicks = sicks + Val(gvRow.Cells(18).Value)

                                End If
                            End If

                            If Not IsDBNull(gvRow.Cells(20).Value) Then
                                'Dim strNgheo As Integer = gvRow.Cells(19).Value
                                ' If strNgheo = (gvRow.Cells(19).Value = True) Then
                                If gvRow.Cells(20).Value > 0 Then

                                    HoN8 = HoN8 + 1
                                    ' ElseIf gvRow.Cells(19).Value = False Then
                                    '    End
                                    students = students + Val(gvRow.Cells(20).Value)

                                End If
                            End If
                        End If


                    End If
                Next

                Form5.Label32.Text = HoN5.ToString
                Form5.Label31.Text = ORPHENS.ToString

                Form5.Label29.Text = HoN6.ToString
                Form5.Label28.Text = families.ToString

                Form5.Label26.Text = HoN7.ToString
                Form5.Label25.Text = sicks.ToString

                Form5.Label23.Text = HoN8.ToString
                Form5.Label22.Text = students.ToString

                Form5.Label35.Text = Val(HoN8.ToString) + Val(HoN7.ToString) + Val(HoN6.ToString) + Val(HoN5.ToString)
                Form5.Label34.Text = Val(ORPHENS.ToString) + Val(families.ToString) + Val(sicks.ToString) + Val(students.ToString)


                Form5.Label53.Text = Val(Form5.Label8.Text) - Val(Form5.Label35.Text)
                Form5.Label52.Text = Val(Form5.Label9.Text) - Val(Form5.Label34.Text)

                Form5.Label50.Text = Val(Form5.Label11.Text) - Val(Form5.Label32.Text)
                Form5.Label49.Text = Val(Form5.Label10.Text) - Val(Form5.Label31.Text)

                Form5.Label47.Text = Val(Form5.Label14.Text) - Val(Form5.Label29.Text)
                Form5.Label46.Text = Val(Form5.Label13.Text) - Val(Form5.Label28.Text)

                Form5.Label44.Text = Val(Form5.Label17.Text) - Val(Form5.Label26.Text)
                Form5.Label43.Text = Val(Form5.Label16.Text) - Val(Form5.Label25.Text)

                Form5.Label41.Text = Val(Form5.Label20.Text) - Val(Form5.Label23.Text)
                Form5.Label40.Text = Val(Form5.Label19.Text) - Val(Form5.Label22.Text)

            End If
```

Comment: example code/data/anything source?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: @IsiahMeadows code added

Comment: @JDOaktown code added

Comment: Wow that's a lot of code! I think you'd be best off debugging through and work out where you missed a null check. Would take a long time for someone here to replicate the code and db

Comment: the problem is throw debugging no error happened it only happened when run it as exe file@JKerny